# window.scrollTo does not work when react modal is opened

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactModal from 'react-modal';


const Modal = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
     window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [])

  return (
        <ReactModal
        >
            {children}
        </ReactModal>
  )
}
```

I want to scroll to top when react modal is opened. For this I put "window.scrollTo(0, 0)" into useEffect. But when react modal is opened it doesn't work. Why doesn't it work properly? Here is an example:

Answer (score 0):

Try alternative solution with ref:

```
const Modal = () => {

  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      divRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "auto" }); // or "smooth" behavior
  }, []);

  return (
        <ReactModal>
              <div ref={divRef}>{children}</div>  // put the divRef to the place/div you want 
        </ReactModal>
  )
}
```